# Plotting a Pandas series in Matplotlib/seaborn

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying an alternate way to visualize a pandas series using matplotlib/seaborn. But I am not able to do it. Is there any way?

I have no problem visualizing it using the df.plot() method of pandas.

```
df2.groupby('Company').Company.count()
```

Data looks like this:

```
100    a
101    b
102    c
103    d
104    a
105    c
106    d
107    b
108    a
109    c
```

Comment: Can you add some data and what you are trying to plot?  You can get Seaborn style while using pandas plot by import seaborn as sns then using sns.set().

Comment: I have added the sample data.

Answer (score 3):

You could use seaborn's `countplot`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
test = pd.DataFrame()
test["Company"] = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "c", "d", "b", "a", "c"]
ax=sns.countplot(test["Company"])
plt.show()
```

[image: showing the resulting graph]

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to the answer given by @Orysza , in case you want the Series **sorted** for plotting, you could use the Series' in-built method `value_counts`

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
tmp = pd.DataFrame()
tmp["vals"] = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "c", "d", "b", "a", "c"]
tmp_valc = tmp["vals"].value_counts()
tmp_valc.head()
```

[image: output after value_counts()]

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(5,5))
g = sns.barplot(x=tmp_valc.index, y=tmp_valc)
t = g.set(title="Value counts of Pandas Series")
```

[image: Graph of value counts]